# ffmpeg with python subprocess Popen

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, subprocess

I'm trying to record webcam video from python using ffmpeg. The following ffmpeg works properly when run from the cmd

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -rtbufsize 2000M -i video="HP HD Camera":audio="Headset (realme Buds Wireless 2 Neo Hands-Free AG Audio)" -y -vcodec libx264 -crf 24 output.mp4
```

I have checked the audio and video inputs with

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

Now when I try to call the command using subprocess problem happens. I can just pass the whole command like this

```py
import subprocess, time
recorder = subprocess.Popen('ffmpeg -f dshow -rtbufsize 2000M -i video="HP HD Camera":audio="Headset (realme Buds Wireless 2 Neo Hands-Free AG Audio)" -y -vcodec libx264 -crf 24 output.mp4', shell=True)
time.sleep(10)
recorder.terminate()
recorder.kill()
```

Now, as this is run with `shell=True` this won't terminate the recording and I have checked different solution, but they won't work either. So, I opted for `shell=False`. I tried with

```
recorder = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg', '-f', 'dshow', '-rtbufsize', '2000M', '-t', '60', '-i', 'video="HP HD Camera":audio="Headset (realme Buds Wireless 2 Neo Hands-Free AG Audio)"', '-y', '-vcodec', 'libx264', '-crf', '24', 'output.mp4'],shell=False)
```

This throws the error

```
[dshow @ 0000024f2becd540] Could not find video device with name ["HP HD Camera"] among source devices of type video.
video="HP HD Camera":audio="Headset (realme Buds Wireless 2 Neo Hands-Free AG Audio)": I/O error
```

Then, I tried

```py
recorder = subprocess.Popen(['ffmpeg', '-f', 'dshow', '-rtbufsize', '2000M', '-t', '60', '-i', 'video=HP HD Camera:audio=Headset (realme Buds Wireless 2 Neo Hands-Free AG Audio)', '-y', '-vcodec', 'libx264', '-crf', '24', 'output.mp4'],shell=False)
```

This creates the output, but the video is not playable.
How to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We may add double quotes for letting Python `subprocess` know the string is one argument, and we have to close FFmpeg gracefully.

Adding double quotes:
Replace the following part `video="HP HD Camera":audio="Headset (realme Buds Wireless 2 Neo Hands-Free AG Audio)"` with:
`"video=""HP HD Camera"":audio=""Headset (realme Buds Wireless 2 Neo Hands-Free AG Audio)"""`
Doubling the quotes `""` is required because `"` is between quotes `" ... "`.

We may also use it without the `""`: `"video=HP HD Camera:audio=Headset (realme Buds Wireless 2 Neo Hands-Free AG Audio)"`.

---

For getting a playable file, we have to close FFmpeg **gracefully**.
For simply recording 10 seconds, we may add `-t 10` argument.

For closing FFmpeg gracefully programmatically, we may write `'q'.encode("GBK")` to `stdin` pipe of FFmpeg sub-process.
Writing `q` simulates that `q` key is pressed by the user (stop recording).

- Add `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` argument to `subprocess.Popen`.
- After `time.sleep(10)` add:

  ```
   recorder.stdin.write('q'.encode("GBK"))  # Simulate user pressing q key
   recorder.communicate()
  ```
- Add `recorder.wait()` (instead of `recorder.terminate()` and `recorder.kill()`).

---

As good practice we may also add `shlex.split(...)` for converting the command line to a list of arguments.
In Windows it supposed to work without it, but in Linux it's not.

Code sample:

```python
import subprocess, time, shlex

recorder = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split('ffmpeg -f dshow -rtbufsize 2000M -t 60 -i """video=HP HD Camera:audio=Headset (realme Buds Wireless 2 Neo Hands-Free AG Audio)"":""audio=Headset (realme Buds Wireless 2 Neo Hands-Free AG Audio)"""'
                                        ' -y -vcodec libx264 -crf 24 output.mp4'), stdin=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)

time.sleep(10)

recorder.stdin.write('q'.encode("GBK"))  # Simulate user pressing q key
recorder.communicate()
recorder.wait()
```

Comment: gracefully closing solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: I need to know one thing,ifyou can help. this ffmpeg command write the whole video at when the command is closed/completed. Is there a way to write the buffer continuously to the disk?

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50576757/4926757). I don't know if it's working... Windows may update the file size only when it is closed. What is the purpose?